# Can (woocommerce_before_variations_form) be moved above (woocommerce_single_product_summary)?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook, hook-woocommerce

I understand this may be elementary for those on this forum, but I'm trying to learn. I am trying to move Product Variations, which I believe are in ‘woocommerce_before_variations_form’, on Single Product Page to above the Product Title, Price, and everything else in the ‘woocommerce_single_product_summary’. See diagram.

[image: diagram of desired field move]

The code I have tried is:

```
function move_variations(){ ?>
  </div>
  <div class="summary entry-summary">
<?php }
add_action('woocommerce_before_variations_form', 'move_variations', 1);
```

Placed at the bottom of my child theme’s function.php file.
It is moving the Variations and everything below them (buy buttons, description) to below the main product image.

Anyone know what I need to fix?

Comment: You can move entire add to cart form but not some parts of the form.

Comment: Helga over at Slack / Woo group gave me this, which does work to do what I wanted (it just doesn't work on my theme):

Comment: function 
kia_relocate_variable_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;
 
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) {
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'kia_relocate_variable_add_to_cart' );